# What are some alternative definitions for a circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: geometry, definition, circles

So if we take the "standard" definition of a circle in $\mathbb R^2$ to be

$$\text{Set of all points}~(x,y) ~\text{with}~ |(x,y)-M|=r, ~\text{where}~ r>0 ~\text{is the radius and}~ M\in \mathbb R^2 ~\text{is the center of the circle.}$$

then one could change the restriction $r>0$ to $|(x,y)-M|=|r|>0$, so it would still be the same object even with negative values for r (is this a correct assumption by the way?).

On Wikipedia, I found two. Euclid's:

> A circle is a plane figure bounded by one curved line, and such that all straight lines drawn from a certain point within it to the bounding line, are equal. The bounding line is called its circumference and the point, its centre.

and another one where a circle is an Ellipse with coincidental foci.

Now I'm wondering if there are more complex alternative definitions for a circle.

Edit: [A parametric definition obviously.](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/40f68942-4a86-409d-8536-6c74723d0808)

Comment: You also have $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$, or $[0,1]/_{\sim}$ where $$x\sim y\iff \begin{cases}x=y&\text{if }x,y\in (0,1)\\x,y\in \{0,1\}&\text{otherwise}\end{cases},$$ and I guess plenty others...

Comment: I have no idea, but don't pay attention to it...

Comment: There is also $y = y_0 \pm \sqrt{r^2 - (x - x_0)^2} = y_0 \pm \sqrt{ r^2 - x_0^2 - x^2 + 2 x x_0 }$, and $$\left\lbrace \begin{aligned} x &= x_0 + r \cos \theta \\ y &= y_0 + r \sin\theta \\ \end{aligned} \right.$$ where $r$ is the radius, and $(x_0, y_0)$ is the center.

Comment: @BlabbotheVerbose Thank you, why not post it as an answer?

Comment: @Surb Those are not definitions of a circle. A circle is more than its topological and algebraic structure, it also has a very important **geometrical** structure.

Comment: You can also characterize the circle using the isoperimetric inequality as far as I remember. Other, somewhat similar, characterization are discussed here: Herda, Hans. "A characterization of circles and other closed curves." The American Mathematical Monthly 81.2 (1974): 146-149.

Comment: "one could change the restriction r>0 to |r|>0,"  Well, no because $|(x,y)−M| \ge 0$.  ....

Comment: @jjagmath I can turn a circle into an ellipse or a square just by changing the metric. Any convex set that's symmetric about the $x$ and $y$ axis can be a circle.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Surb suggested $\Bbb R / \Bbb Z$, and you are talking about an $x$ and $y$ axis? What the meaning of convex symmetric set in that "definition" of circle (which doesn't include the ambient space $\Bbb R^2$)?

Comment: @fleablood Then additionally $|(x,y)-M|=|r|$?

Comment: @jjagmath I'm just saying that you can change the geometry with the tradition definition of a circle as a locus of points equidistant from a fixed point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are certainly hundreds of variously interesting definitions. To give three:

1. A circle is in the plane the closed curve which has the smallest length for a given area.
   Or, to say it differently, it is the only curve for which the isoperimetric inequality is an equality.
   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isoperimetric_inequality
2. A circle is a curve with constant, non-null, plane curvature.
   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature#Circle
3. A circle centered on the origin of a polar coordinates ($r, \theta$) system is the curve with equation $r(\theta) = c$ (constant) $\ge 0$.
   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Circle